# How to make a local variable useable in other methods

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to C# and I can't figure out how to make one of my variables accessible in another method. It is a program that takes calories and fat grams found in a food and then presents the percentage of fat and the number of calories of fat. Then there is a checkbox asking whether you want it to see if it is a low fat food or not. When checked, I want it to take the result of the percentage of fat and show if it is low fat or not. But since `decimal percentCalsFromFat` is a local variable, it isn't recognized under the checkbox code. I read that I can promote it to a class level scope but I don't know how I would write that out and where exactly to put it in the code for it to work. Then afterwards it has to display the results at the bottom of the label box. Here is the code:

This is how the application is supposed to look when finished:

[image]

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //local variables
    decimal totalCals;
    decimal fatGramsInFood;
    decimal calsFromFat;
    decimal percentCalsFromFat;
    //Get the calories and fat grams.
    totalCals = decimal.Parse(numOfCaloriesTextBox.Text);
    fatGramsInFood = decimal.Parse(numOfFatGramsTextBox.Text);
    //Determine whether the calories and fat grams are higher than 0.
    if (totalCals >= 0 && fatGramsInFood >= 0)
    {
        if (totalCals > fatGramsInFood)
        {
            //Calculate calories from fat.
            calsFromFat = fatGramsInFood * 9;
            //Display the calories from fat.
            resultsLabel.Text = calsFromFat.ToString();
            //Calculate percentage of calories from fat.
            percentCalsFromFat = calsFromFat / totalCals;
            //Display percentage of calories from fat.
            resultsLabel.Text = "The number of calories from fat:" + Environment.NewLine;
            resultsLabel.Text += "Percentage of calories from fat:" + percentCalsFromFat.ToString("p") + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            //Display an error message "calories must to be higher than fat grams".
            MessageBox.Show("Calories must be higher than fat grams");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Display an error message "calories and fat grams need be higher than 0".
        MessageBox.Show("Calories and fat grams need to be higher than 0");
    }
}

private void foodLowFatCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal percentCalsFromFat;
    if (foodLowFatCheckBox.Checked && percentCalsFromFat <= 30)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = "The food is considered low fat";
    }
    else
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = "The food is not considered low fat";
    }
}
```

Comment: `private decimal percentCalsFromFat;` outside both methods.

Comment: You should probably put the `foodLowFatCheckBox_CheckedChanged` calculation in your `CalculateButton_Click`.

Comment: **where** you declare a variable determines its `scope`. if you declare it as a local variable, thats it, it's local.  full stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it accessible every where like this:

```
namespace Program4_10
{
    private double calsFromFat, percentCalsFromFat;
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            percentCalsFromFat = calsFromFat = 0;
        }
        private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //local variables
            double totalCals;
            double fatGramsInFood;
            //Get the calories and fat grams.
            totalCals = double.Parse(numOfCaloriesTextBox.Text);
            fatGramsInFood = double.Parse(numOfFatGramsTextBox.Text);
            //Determine whether the calories and fat grams are higher than 0.
            if (totalCals >= 0 && fatGramsInFood >= 0)
            {
                if (totalCals > fatGramsInFood)
                {
                    //Calculate calories from fat.
                    calsFromFat = fatGramsInFood * 9;
                    //Calculate percentage of calories from fat.
                    percentCalsFromFat = calsFromFat / totalCals;
                    DisplayText();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Display an error message "calories must to be higher than fat grams".
                    MessageBox.Show("Calories must be higher than fat grams");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Display an error message "calories and fat grams need be higher than 0".
                MessageBox.Show("Calories and fat grams need to be higher than 0");
            }
        }
        private void foodLowFatCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayText();
        }
        private void DisplayText()
        {
            //Display percentage of calories from fat.
            resultsLabel.Text = "The number of calories from fat:" + calsFromFat.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            resultsLabel.Text += "Percentage of calories from fat:" + percentCalsFromFat.ToString("p") + Environment.NewLine;
            if (foodLowFatCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                if (percentCalsFromFat <= 0.3)
                    resultsLabel.Text += "The food is considered low fat";
                else
                    resultsLabel.Text += "The food is not considered low fat";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201178/discussion-on-answer-by-abdelaziz-abdellatef-how-to-make-a-local-variable-useabl).